# Javadoc like documentation for C#'s XML comments

Tags: c#, xslt, documentation, comments, javadoc

I'm looking for something to turn my C# XML comments into documentation. I don't like CHM's, nor MSDN's look and feel. I love using the javadocs. They're easy to navigate, and everything is accessible. I am looking for a tool I can use to convert the comments in my code to a javadoc like look and feel.

Is there something that does this? I've tried Sandcastle and its various GUI's but they don't do what I want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a tool recommendation, and because there are already a zillion other Q&As that recommend Doxygen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you can use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) ?

Answer (score 3):

Please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546053/anyone-using-ndoc-or-a-similar-tool-to-help-with-system-documentation/
You will find there a brief overview of different commercial and opensource tools

My vote is for [SandCastle](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle)

Comment: As of August 5, 2015, the link to the SO question does not exist.

Comment: As of Nov 18 '14 at 3:04 actually, was dead long before you tried it :p

Comment: SandCastle is also mentioned in [I want to create documentation in C#, something similar to javadoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608673/i-want-to-create-documentation-in-c-something-similar-to-javadoc).

Answer (score 1):

ndoc is very similar to JavaDoc. I'd recommend it: http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/